# BodePlot of Warburg impedance - Errors

Tags: plotting, control-systems

I'm trying to plot the Bode diagrams of the Warburg impedance (A=1, s=jw):

$$Z=\frac{A}{\sqrt{\omega}}+\frac{A}{j\sqrt{\omega}}$$

$$Z=A \sqrt{\frac{j}{s}}+\frac{A}{j}\sqrt{\frac{j}{s}}$$

```
BodePlot[TransferFunctionModel[Sqrt[I/s] + 1/Sqrt[I s], s]]
```

idem with:

```
BodePlot[TransferFunctionModel[Sqrt[I/s] (1 - I), s]]
```

but Mathematica gives me a series of error. Is it possible to plot it in Mathematica? Is there another way to do it?

```
PolynomialGCD::lrgexp: Exponent is out of bounds for function PolynomialGCD.

TransferFunctionModel::npnd: Unable to automatically separate polynomial numerators and denominators in TransferFunctionModel[{{{(1+Sqrt[Times[<<2>>]] Sqrt[Times[<<2>>]]) Sqrt[s]}},Sqrt[I s] Sqrt[s]},s]. Try simplifying the object.

TransferFunctionModel::invsys: TransferFunctionModel[{{{(1+Sqrt[Times[<<2>>]] Sqrt[Times[<<2>>]]) Sqrt[s]}},Sqrt[I s] Sqrt[s]},s] is not a valid TransferFunctionModel, StateSpaceModel, AffineStateSpaceModel, or NonlinearStateSpaceModel.

PolynomialGCD::lrgexp: Exponent is out of bounds for function PolynomialGCD.

TransferFunctionModel::npnd: Unable to automatically separate polynomial numerators and denominators in TransferFunctionModel[{{{(1+Sqrt[Times[<<2>>]] Sqrt[Times[<<2>>]]) Sqrt[s]}},Sqrt[I s] Sqrt[s]},s]. Try simplifying the object.

TransferFunctionModel::invsys: TransferFunctionModel[{{{(1+Sqrt[Times[<<2>>]] Sqrt[Times[<<2>>]]) Sqrt[s]}},Sqrt[I s] Sqrt[s]},s] is not a valid TransferFunctionModel, StateSpaceModel, AffineStateSpaceModel, or NonlinearStateSpaceModel.

SystemsModelDimensions::invsys: TransferFunctionModel[Sqrt[I/s]+1/Sqrt[I s],s] is not a valid TransferFunctionModel, StateSpaceModel, AffineStateSpaceModel, or NonlinearStateSpaceModel.

SystemsModelDimensions::invsys: TransferFunctionModel[Sqrt[I/s]+1/Sqrt[I s],s] is not a valid TransferFunctionModel, StateSpaceModel, AffineStateSpaceModel, or NonlinearStateSpaceModel.

Array::ilsmn: Single or list of non-negative machine-sized integers expected at position 2 of Array[SystemsModelExtract[TransferFunctionModel[Sqrt[I Power[<<2>>]]+1/Sqrt[I s],s],#2,#1]&,SystemsModelDimensions[TransferFunctionModel[Sqrt[I/s]+1/Sqrt[I s],s]]].
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd guess that `BodePlot` cannot handle transfer functions that aren't ratios of polynomials. Perhaps you should seek a rational approximation for the domain of interest.

Comment: @JohnDoty It's above all `TranferFunctionModel` that only accepts ratios of polynomials (with the addition of delays)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is a plot of the impedance, and given @JohnDoty observation that `TransferFunctionModel` is expecting rational polynomials, you can roll your own

```
z[s_] := Sqrt[I/s] + 1/Sqrt[I*s]; 
Column[{
  LogLinearPlot[20*Log10[Abs[z[I*w]]], {w, 1, 1000}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"], 
  LogLinearPlot[Arg[z[I*w]]/Degree, {w, 1, 1000}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
}]
```

Also, [here](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/WarburgImpedance/) is a relevant Wolfram demonstration.

Comment: Hello @DanielW, thank you so much for your excellent solution.